# Would the name of a church need to be capitalised in Spanish?

Tags: vocabulario, uso-de-mayúsculas

This is the name of the church in Spanish: *el faro de luz*.

Comment: ...........Yes.

Comment: Googling the name brings up churches like this (note the capitalisation): [**Iglesia el Faro de Luz**](https://www.ivictorycenter.org/th_event/iglesia-el-faro-de-luz-servicio-de-adoracion/)

Comment: Check capitalisation rules in Spanish in http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=BapzSnotjD6n0vZiTp

Answer (score 3):

Yes, In Spanish, the name of a church would be capitalized in much the same way as you would capitalize the title of a book (in English): the first and last word and all main words.  It is also common to see the name of a church with all words (including "de" or "del") capitalized, particularly on signs and such.

Answer (score 3):

[Fundéu BBVA](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/mayusculas-y-minusculas-en-nombre-de-iglesias-956/) says this on the topic:

> Las denominaciones de las iglesias constan de dos partes, una genérica (*iglesia, iglesia arciprestal, basílica,* etc.), que se escribe con inicial **minúscula**, y otra específica (*de San Jaime, de El Salvador*…), que se escribe con inicial **mayúscula**. Así pues, la forma apropiada de escribir el primero de sus ejemplos sería **«iglesia arciprestal de San Jaime»**. La palabra *catedral* se escribe siempre con inicial minúscula: **«la catedral de Burgos»**.

As such, it would be:

> «iglesia el Faro de Luz»

unless it was at the start of a sentence/the title of something, in which the first word would be capitalised.

---

<sup>The [RAE's DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=BapzSnotjD6n0vZiTp), in its section on capital letters, doesn't make mention of churches, but says this about the names of *buildings*:</sup>

> <sup>**MAYÚSCULAS**</sup>
>
> <sup>**4. Uso de mayúscula inicial independientemente de la puntuación.**</sup>
>
> <sup>**4.14.** Los sustantivos y adjetivos que componen el nombre de entidades, organismos, departamentos o divisiones administrativas, edificios, monumentos, establecimientos públicos, partidos políticos, etc.:</sup>
>
> - <sup>*el Ministerio de Hacienda, la Casa Rosada, la Biblioteca Nacional, el Museo de Bellas Artes, la Real Academia de la Historia, el Instituto Caro y Cuervo, la Universidad Nacional Autónoma de México, la Facultad de Medicina, el Departamento de Recursos Humanos, el Área de Gestión Administrativa, la Torre de Pisa, el Teatro Real, el Café de los Artistas, el Partido Demócrata.*</sup>
>
> <sup>También se escribe con mayúscula el término que en el uso corriente nombra de forma abreviada una determinada institución o edificio:</sup>
>
> - <sup>*la Nacional* (por *la Biblioteca Nacional*), *el Cervantes* (por *el Instituto Cervantes*), *la Complutense* (por *la Universidad Complutense*), *el Real* (por *el Teatro Real*).</sup>